# Issue on TCP reassembly

Tags: tcp, lua

I'm new to LUA and have successfully written a dissector to dissect a custom protocol over TCP (for data being sent over network between 2 modules in my application) for non-fragmented TCP case.

But this doesn't work when the TCP data is sent split into multiple packets. After some research, found out that the only way to do this in lua script is to use pkt.desegment_len and pkt.desegment_offset. But with modified code, when I open a given pcap in wireshark (with this dissector lua script plugged in) I see those pkt info of those packets as - [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU] and nothing else in the details (tree) section.

My protocol contains few header fields, where 6th and 7th bytes denote the length of given packet.
Here is my code, let me know if I'm missing something or can somebody give me a sample working script for this reassembled TCP packet handling.

```
function p_Kod_CALLP_MED.dissector (buf, pkt, root)

    local desiredPacketLen = buf(5,2):uint() 

    -- if not enough data indicate how much more we need
    if desiredPacketLen > buf:len() then
      pkt.desegment_len = desiredPacketLen - buf:len()
      pkt.desegment_offset = 0
      return
    end

    -- have more than needed so set offset for next dissection
    if buf:len() >= desiredPacketLength then
      pkt.desegment_len = DESEGMENT_ONE_MORE_SEGMENT
      pkt.desegment_offset = desiredPacketLength
    end
```

-- Remaining logic like adding to the tree etc

Comment: Stumbling over the same problem ­– did you ever find a fix?